# Converting data in a file to HTML in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Apologies for the lack of crucial info. More details included.

I am using Node.JS/Express/Jade to read data from a file to form a newsletter. When injecting the data into the jade template, everything looks good until I try to add HTML tags.

Here is the router page which calls the Jade template:

```
var newsletterContent = require('../data');
var newsletter = require('../newsletter');

for(var number in newsletterContent) {
   newsletterContent[number] = newsletter(newsletterContent[number]);
}

exports.newsletter = function(req, res){
    var number = req.param('number');

if (typeof newsletterContent[number] === 'undefined') {
    res.status(404).json({status: 'No information for specified input parameter'});
} else {
    res.json(newsletterContent[number].getStoryHighlights());
}
};

exports.current = function (req, res) {
res.render('newsletter', {
    title: 'All Newsletter Content', 
    newsletterContent: newsletterContent
});
};
```

The data file is a simple JSON file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "Story1": {
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "We set a new speed record for this thing <blockquote>It was    amazing</blockquote> ",
        "link":"http://something.com",
        "sidebar":"sidebar",
    },
```

Here is the block of Jade that displays the data. I would like to do blockquotes, paragraphs, and all of that. I know that Jade cares about indents and other special character placement. I am not sure how to account for that in a JSON data file.

```
block content
h1= title
p here is a list of stories that we like:
  ul
  each newsletter, index in newsletterContent
     - newsletter = newsletter.getStoryHighlights()
     li= newsletter.title + ':' + newsletter.description
```

getStoryHighlights is declared in the newsletter module which is not included here. I am add more files if that helps. Appreciate the help!

Is there a simple trick to allow the text to be stylized by the CSS when I inject the data into the jade template?

Comment: With all due respect, how can you possibly expect anyone to diagnose the problem with A. no template code & B. no indication as to what sort of output you expect.

Comment: What does this have to do with Node.js, Express, or Jade?  Nothing.  This is an HTML/CSS question.  Like James said, show your templae code and elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Initial post is updated. Thanks for your help!